# Need to break out of a while loop after 5 questions

Tags: java, loops, count

I am trying to break the loop after 5 math questions.
The Return statement is required in this public static.
I cannot seem to get the program to break the loop.

```
count=0;
while(count < 5)
{
    System.out.println("Please answer the following problem: ");
    System.out.println(randomInt1 + "+" + randomInt2 + "=");
    answer = keyboard.nextDouble();   

    if(answer != (randomInt1 + randomInt2))
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, that is not correct.");
    }     
    else if(answer == (randomInt1 + randomInt2))
    {
        System.out.println("Nice!");
    }
    count++;
    break;
}
```

Comment: You have `break;` at the end so you are breaking the loop. This is where stepping through the code in your debugger would show you where the problem is.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  I am very new to this, and am not aware of a debugger.

Comment: The break in the code is the only way i can find that asks a different question each time. without the break, it asks the same question five times, and then another question 5 times

Comment: If you want to repeat 5 questions, you need to put these into the loop.

Comment: If you want a new question, you need new random numbers

Answer (score 3):

Move the `break` inside the `else if`. Your loop will either stop when you get the answer correct or when `count` is greater than or equal to 5.

Currently, your loop only executes once, then you break out of it.

Also, if you want to ask a different question, then you need new Random numbers each time through the loop.

Comment: Without the 'break', it asks the same math question over and over 5 times, and the asks another math question over and over 5 times.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. See edits

Comment: How do I check those?

Comment: Just re-read the answer. Maybe refresh the page. I changed my original answer to tell you to move the break instead of get rid of it

Answer (score -2):

dont use break,it will stop automatically when the condition fails.remove else if and make it just else if the value is not equal in if case means then it should be equal in else case.if you need to stop when user enters a correct value just move the break statement inside the if statement,if he doest answer it correctly then it will ask the same question again and again till the condition fails.

```
count=0;

while(count < 5)
{
 System.out.println("Please answer the following problem: ");
System.out.println(randomInt1 + "+" + randomInt2 + "=");
answer = keyboard.nextDouble();   

 if(answer == (randomInt1 + randomInt2))
{
 System.out.println("Nice!");
 break;
}     
 else 
{
 System.out.println("Sorry, that is not correct.");
}

 count++;

}
```

Comment: Does this compile at all? You've got a syntax error, check it. It's near the else if statement.

Comment: I dont have any errors on my side, no.

Comment: no,it will work good